# Using Command + [number] to go between terminals

Tags: terminal, mojave, window-manager

Before I upgraded to Mojave I was able to use `command` + `[number]` to go between various windows in Terminal. After the upgrade that ability is gone and I am unsure how to get it back. Is it possible to enable this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terminal.app `Command+[number]` shortcut was remapped to switch between tabs instead of windows.  The new shortcut is `Command+Option+[number]`.

If you want the original shortcut back, turn off the "Use Command-1 through Command-9 to switch tabs" preference option under `Terminal -> Preferences -> General`.

Comment: One can also use **⌘`** to switch between an apps windows.